# Restarting HBase automatically when it crashes

Tags: crash, hbase, restart

I am using HBase 0.98.3 in standalone mode. Is there a way for restarting HBase when it crashes? I have tried with supervisord with no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to achieve this, in an ubuntu setting.

Here's my recipe, but YMMV.

```
# hbase-master - HBase Master
#

description     "HBase Master"

start on (local-filesystems
        and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel[!2345]

respawn
console log
setuid hbase
setgid hbase
nice 0
oom score -700
limit nofile 32768 32768
limit memlock unlimited unlimited

exec /usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase master start
```